# Teamcity: Disable triggers project-wide

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a project in which all of the build configurations inherited from the same template. This template contains trigger to run integration tests every day.
Now, I've cloned this project. But I don't want builds in this new project to being run every day by trigger. If I disable the trigger on template, it will alsi be disabled for the first project, what I also don't want. How can I override trigger behaviour for one particular project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was wrong. After cloning the project I've got cloned template for this project as well. So, I can edit this template and reach the result I need.

Comment: The template get copied with the project automatically if it belongs to the project or belongs to a parent project of the source but not target (due to project's hierarchy).